# signal storing in Matlab CAN database

Tags: matlab, can-bus

i'm new with Matlab never used it before, trying to writ a program in Matlab to plot signals.
i have "CAN.dbc" files which are the structure of the CAN message which contains the message ID and the properties of the signals in the message

using canDatabase() i can load the dbc of the wanted message 
and get info on the signals

messageInfo(db, 'EngineMsg')
ans =

```
    Name: 'EngineMsg'
 Comment: ''
      ID: 100
Extended: 0
  Length: 8
 Signals: {2x1 cell}
```

the messages i have are stored in a txt file in the right order

"timestamp 2871634 appId 0x64 length 12 data 0x00 0xe7 0x0b 0x9c 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x46 0x00 0x25 0x1f "

is it possible to load/ store all the messages in the text file into the CAN database in order to plot them later ?

best regards .

Answer (score 0):

Export your CAN traces (ASCII or BLF files) in CANoe to .mat files from a logging block. Then plot your .mat files corresponding to the syntax in [this link](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) in MATLAB after [loading](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) them in your workspace. Type the command plot(YOUR_SIGNAL) in the command window or write it in a MATLAB script (.m file) that you run. Verify before plotting that the signal you want to plot is a (N x 2)-matrix in your .mat file, where N is the number of time stamps you originally traced. You don't need to import or refer to your DBCs in MATLAB when they were there in CANoe to interprete your CAN trace messages (at least one DBC for each CAN channel that has messages containing signals you want to plot later in MATLAB). The DBC is just a database for CAN signals and not a trace. You can not plot CAN Signals having time as x axis without having a trace as a mat file because the DBCs contain no signal course. In other words DBCs contain no signal values for real time stamps like those you get when tracing in the car or running a simulation.